# Why is there timing problem while to fork child processes

Tags: fork, race-condition

When I took a look at the reference of 'Launching-Jobs' in [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html#Launching-Jobs), I didn't get this part.

> The shell should also call `setpgid` to put each of its child processes into the new process group. This is because there is a potential **timing problem**: each child process must be put in the process group before it begins executing a *new program*, and the shell depends on having all the child processes in the group before it continues executing. If both the child processes and the shell call setpgid, this ensures that the right things happen no matter which process gets to it first.

There is two method on the link page, `launch_job ()` and `launch_process ()`.
They both call the `setpgid` in order to prevent the **timing problem**.

But I didn't get why is there such a problem.

I guess *new program* means result of `execvp (p->argv[0], p->argv);` in `launch_process()`. And before run execvp, `setpgid (pid, pgid);` is always executed, without same function on `launch_job ()`.

So again, why is there such a problem? (why we have to call `setpgid ();` on `launch_job ()` either?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell wants the process to be in the right process group. If the shell doesn't call `setpgid()` on its child process, there is a window of time during which the child process is not part of the process group, while the shell execution continues. (By calling `setpgid()` the shell can guarantee that the child process is part of the process group after that call).

There is another problem, which is that the child process may execute the new program (via `exec`) before its process group id has been properly set (i.e. before the parent calls `setpgid()`). That is why the child process should also call `setpgid()` (before calling `exec()`).

The description is admittedly pretty bad. There isn't just one problem being solved here; it's really two separate problems. One - the parent (i.e. the shell) wants to have the child process in the right process group. Two - the new program should begin execution only once its process has already been put into the right process group.

Comment: Now I get the basic outline!
Could you explain why 'the shell depends on having all the child processes in the group before it continues executing'?

Comment: It might be a mainly theoretical concern, but, if after forking a shell command was used to send a signal to the process group of the forked process, there would be a window where that was the wrong process group (it would be the shell's own process group).

Comment: It's also because the shell will probably want to call waitpid on the whole process group with `waitpid(-pgid, ...)`, and that won't wait for the processes that call setpgid too late.

Comment: @Pikrass, I'm pretty sure that waiting for a process group doesn't just wait for the processes in the group at the time of the call; it waits for any process in the process group, even if it joined the group after the call to `waitpid`.

Comment: @davmac Yes, but still, there's a race condition. If there's no process in the group at the time of the wait (because they didn't yet call setpgid or they terminated and were already acknowledged), waitpid will immediately return. I had the problem while writing a little shell as an experiment (most of the time because there was only one process intended to be in the group).

Comment: @Pikrass ok, you need to call setpgid from the parent process to avoid this. But that doesn't answer the question, which is why you need to call `setpgid` in both the child and parent process, and what race condition this avoids. The problem that you mention is one that I already covered in my answer: "If the shell doesn't call setpgid() on its child process, there is a window of time during which the child process is not part of the process group, while the shell execution continues"

Comment: @davmac "The problem that you mention is one that I already covered in my answer" => I know that, I just wanted to provide a more explicit example of your first point. :) Sorry for the misunderstanding, I should have mentioned it.